# Overriding Servlet container session storage

Tags: java, servlets

If want to store my web application session to different storage, because one every new request user might use different node, is it possible to override default container session storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to overrride anything. It should come with the server you are using. You need to look at "Session replication". In clustering environments, the app server can be configured to replicate session across nodes.

You will need to check documentation of the app server you are using to figure out how this can be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the [memcached-session-manager](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/). It stores the session in external memcached server and works for both sticky-session and non-sticky-session(which is your case) scenario.